# Adding fields to item in scrapy from list

Tags: scrapy, field

I have a long list of fields to add to a scrapy item but can't figure out how to do it. Basically I am trying to get the output of

```
class myItem(scrapy.Item):
    a = scrapy.field()
    b = scrapy.field()
```

But I want to create it from a list like

```
['a','b']
```

I tried

```
fields = ['a','b']

def generateFields(fields):  
    item = myItem()
    for field in fields:
        field = scrapy.Field()
    return item
```

But that didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage it by using python magic method `__dict__` pretty much as:

```
fields = ['a', 'b', 'c']
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    def __init__(self):
        for f in fields:
            self.__dict__[f] = scrapy.field()

my_item = MyItem()
```

And so on... 
Seems that my previous comment is valid for usual python classes, not for `scrapy.Item` class. Following code is working:

```
from scrapy import Item, Field

fields = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def generate_item(fields):
    item = Item()
    for f in fields:
        item.fields[f] = Field()
    return item

 item_instance = generate_item(fields)
 item_instance['a'] = 'some_value'
 item_instance['b'] = 12
 print(item_instance)
```

Comment: I hate this editor (:

**item.__dict__[field] = scrapy.Field()**

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried running your code (first box) and when I try to return the item I get 

File "C:\Users\Joe\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\item.py", line 74, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)

AttributeError: _values

Comment: Thanks! That worked, except item.fields[f] = Field() should be item.fields[f] = scrapy.Field()